# Background color not transparent under current line number

Tags: colorscheme

In the following image, you can see that 79 has a darker background than other numbers... I tried to see where to change the background color for that but couldn't... Could anyone help?
[image]

Comment: What colorscheme?

Comment: I'm using the [gotham](https://github.com/whatyouhide/gotham-contrib) colorscheme in konsole as well as the [gotham colorsheme](https://github.com/whatyouhide/vim-gotham) inside vim. Then I edited my Konsole background to be 15% transparent.

Comment: https://github.com/whatyouhide/vim-gotham/blob/master/colors/gotham.vim check out the highlight on LineNr and CursorLineNr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it using `highlight clear CursorLineNR` since my terminal colorscheme was the one which had some transparency to it's background.